# How to make 'zsh' to stop autocorrect for some words?

Tags: zsh, autocorrect, oh-my-zsh

I'm using `zsh` +  `oh-my-zsh`.

How can I make `zsh` to stop *auto-correct* for some words?

e.g. When I do `make install` or `sudo apt-get install`, it always tries to auto correct `install` to `INSTALL`. Can I make it NOT do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using aliases like this?

```
alias install='nocorrect install'
```

Or

```
alias apt-get='nocorrect apt-get'
```

Alternatively, this more drastic option

```
unsetopt correct_all
```